# How to pass, EXCEL getting value from pivot table more that 255 characters

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[End Balance@FCY]",wrkFC!$B$7,"[GLCOA_A].[GLCOA_A]","[GLCOA_A].[GLCOA_A].[L1 NM].&[TOTAL value].&[TOTAL value and value value value(VVVV)].&[TOTAL ].&[DUE VALUE VALUE vaLUE $ OTHER VALUE ITEMS].&[DUE VALUE & OTHER VALUE ITEMS (VCOCI)].&[FOREIGHN VALUE & OTHER VALUE ITEMS (VOVI)].&[FOREIGN VALUE AND OTHER VALUE ITEMS (VVVV)]","[Currency].[Currency]","[Currency].[Currency].[Curr ID].&[USD]")
```

These excel pivot data value cannot be changed. how do I pass this value to excel cell so that I can get the real value?
Excel states "Text values are limited to 255 characters. To create text values longer than 255 charaters in a fromla, use CONCATENATE function or the concatenation operator (&)".

Please help.

Comment: How do you convert to long text? just in case....

Comment: Okay now what I did was GETPIVOTDATA(Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4) Thanks